# Simulate a non-homogeneous poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, simulation, poisson-process

I was trying to simulate a non-homogeneous poisson process with hazard rate function
$$
\lambda(t)=3+\sin(2\pi t)
$$
I tried to use the property that given $N=n$, arrivals in $[0,T]$ are distributed with pdf
$$
f(t)=\frac{\lambda(t)}{\int_0^T\lambda(s)ds}\textbf{1}\{t\in[0,T]\}=\frac{1}{15}(3+\sin(2\pi t))\textbf{1}\{t\in[0,T]\}
$$
first generate a poisson r.v. with mean $\int_0^T\lambda(t)dt$ and then generate the arrivals using the pdf above but ran into a problem. I cannot find a method to simulate $t$ with pdf $f(t)$

I tried using inverse transformation but the cdf is $F(t)=-\frac{1}{15}(3t-2\pi\cos(2\pi t))$ and I cannot find a close form solution for $t$ in terms of $F(t)$. Any suggestions as for how should I proceed? maybe using acceptance-rejection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: assuming $T=5$.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an inversion numerically, if analytically is not possible. Here are different approaches to generate nonhomogenous poisson processes, if inversion is not appropriate:
[https://web.ics.purdue.edu/~pasupath/PAPERS/2011pasB.pdf](https://web.ics.purdue.edu/%7Epasupath/PAPERS/2011pasB.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Rejection would be simple and fast here.  You can just draw $n$ points uniformly distributed on $[0,T]$ where $n$ is drawn from a Poisson distribution with mean $4T$.  Apply the function $\lambda$ to these points and subtract random numbers uniformly distributed from $0$ to $4$.  Keep the points where this result is positive.  The Mathematica code for this is

`sim[T_] := Module[{n, raw, mask}, n = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[4T]]; raw = RandomReal[{0, T}, n]; mask = Positive /@ (3 + Sin[2 Pi raw] - RandomReal[{0, 4}, n]); Pick[raw, mask]]`